# Why is admin.py never loaded?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm setting up the django admin on a project.

I've created `admin.py` files in each of my apps (just as I have on previous projects). However the `admin.py` modules are not being loaded. My models aren't registered and I can't break into the code with `pydevd.settrace()`.

If I move my admin code to the end of `models.py` everything works as expected, the models are registered with admin, and the code runs (I can step through it with `pydevd.settrace()`).

So this fails -

```
my_project_app
    __init__.py
    cart
        __init__.py
        models.py
        admin.py
```

But when I add my code to the end of the models.py file everything runs fine -

```
from django.contrib import admin

class CartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Cart, CartAdmin)
```

Obviously I'm going to be configuring the admin so I don't want everything in one module. How do I get my `admin.py` file working? And why have they stopped working (this is the first time I've used django 1.5 - not sure if that's relevant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you call `admin.autodiscover()` in your `urls.py` and it loads everything:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Since you have to do it before trying to use `admin.site.urls`, that's the best place to call it.

Comment: Of course. I took it out. I'm trying to override the AdminSite and use AbstractBaseUser. I've hit problems so I'm working backwards to see what the issue is. I forgot to put the line back in. Thanks Pavel!

Answer (score 3):

In your admin.py file you have to import your models

```
from cart.models import Cart
```

If still it didnot work then Check if you have included

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

in your installed_apps list of settings file then in urls file include

```
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

run manange.py syncdb

run manage.py runserver

check 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

It should work

Comment: Thanks vibhor. Pavel beat you to it, but that all looks good, so +1 from me.